# How to convert an image file into its base64 representation without the leading prefix: "data:image/jpeg;base64" in js&html5

Tags: javascript, html, base64

I have below codes in my frontend:

```
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        _this.imageBase64 = e.target.result;
        alert(_this.imageBase64);
        ...
    }
```

the `alert` function shows that the `imageBase64` is a base64 string, which is  starting with `data:image/jpeg;base64`.

The problem is that, is there any elegant way that I can get the base64 string of the image, without this prefix? (I don't want to use `substring` like function).

Since the server end codes will read this string with the assumption that **it only contains the base64 representation of the image.**

Comment: Why don't you want to use `substring` (or `slice`)?

Comment: I am a java coder, in java we read the image in the disk into an` inputstream`  , and convert the `inputstream` into a base64 string. No useless prefix at all.

Comment: Sure, but why not use `substring` or `slice` to remove the prefix? It's one of the most straightforward solutions, so I'm trying to understand why you don't want to use those sorts of functions.

Comment: `base64Str.split(',').pop()` - then you don't need to know the length of the "header"

Comment: `datauri.split('base64').pop()` can be one way to do if you want to explicitly specify length of header

Comment: Thanks. Just wondering is there any solution without string operation in the front end world?

Comment: @CodeManiac - you'd end up with a leading `,` :p

Comment: @JaromandaX yeah you're right my bad. it should be `base64,` or simply `,` as you suggested

Comment: I don't know of one, because it makes sense to have the metadata, to know what the actual data is. Otherwise, you wouldn't know, if you're dealing with a jpg, png, or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `base64Str.split(',').pop()` is my best choice, as `string.slice(start, stop)` and `string.substring(start, stop)` require the exact index.

Seems that we are getting a `data url`(which has the leading meta data prefix) by using the approach I mentioned. The advantage is that that url can be used directly in some `src` field. This is the reason why we have that prefix in the front end world.